# Stop Python Recognise String as HEX

Tags: python, string, hex

I have a string storing the path of file:

```
mystring='abc\32\32_r.png'
```

However, when I print out mystring. It was converted to:

```
abc\x1a\x1a_r.png
```

How to stop python from converting my text?

Answer (score 2):

Declare it as raw string:

```
mystring=r'abc\32\32_r.png'
```

or you can escape the backslashes:

```
mystring='abc\\32\\32_r.png'
```

(if this is not a keyword argument for function/method, you should put spaces around `=`)